# How do I run three table INNER JOIN in PHP?

Tags: php, inner-join

I need to query several tables for "product tags", based on the producttags table, and subcategorytags table.

Then to produce products where a tag is "shirt".

If I remove the first inner join, and the "`WHERE t.producttag = 'shirt'`", it works.  Same for the subcategorytags section.

But when I try it with both, it doesn't error, but doesn't product anything.

```
SELECT p.datebackinstock, p.datepricedrop, p.id, p.catid, p.subid, p.catname, p.subname, 
       p.title, p.price, p.photoprimary, p.comingsoon, p.rcstock, p.preorder, 
       p.bundleroman1, p.bundleroman2, p.bundleroman3, p.bundleroman4, p.bundleroman5, 
       p.pricedrop  FROM products AS p 

INNER JOIN producttags AS t ON p.id = t.prodid

INNER JOIN subcategorytags AS s ON p.subid = s.subid 

WHERE t.producttag = 'shirt' OR s.tag = 'shirt'
```

Comment: Can you show the structure of you tables?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use left joins for this as you do not know wich tags are set. In your query the row will only be returned if a `producttag` **and** a `subcategorytag` is found. A left join will return the row even if no row in another table is found. Because of this you will also need to do an extra check to make sure the values are not null.

```
SELECT p.datebackinstock, p.datepricedrop, p.id, p.catid, p.subid, p.catname, p.subname, 
       p.title, p.price, p.photoprimary, p.comingsoon, p.rcstock, p.preorder, 
       p.bundleroman1, p.bundleroman2, p.bundleroman3, p.bundleroman4, p.bundleroman5, 
       p.pricedrop  FROM products AS p 

LEFT JOIN producttags AS t ON p.id = t.prodid

LEFT JOIN subcategorytags AS s ON p.subid = s.subid 

WHERE (t.producttag NOT NULL AND t.producttag = 'shirt') OR (s.tag NOT NULL AND s.tag = 'shirt')
```

More information about right and left joins can be found in the [mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/left-join-optimization.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `left outer join` or rather, I would try, I think like:

```
select
    p.`datebackinstock`, 
    p.`datepricedrop`, 
    p.`id`, 
    p.`catid`, 
    p.`subid`, 
    p.`catname`, 
    p.`subname`, 
    p.`title`, 
    p.`price`, 
    p.`photoprimary`, 
    p.`comingsoon`, 
    p.`rcstock`, 
    p.`preorder`, 
    p.`bundleroman1`, 
    p.`bundleroman2`, 
    p.`bundleroman3`, 
    p.`bundleroman4`, 
    p.`bundleroman5`, 
    p.`pricedrop` 
    from `products` p 
    left outer join `producttags` t on p.`id` = t.`prodid`
    left outer join `subcategorytags` s on p.`subid` = s.`subid`
    where t.`producttag` = 'shirt' or s.`tag` = 'shirt'
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. The LEFT JOIN Cracked it.
However, when I use the additional "IS NOT NULL" it doesn't like that.

Comment: @Simon_a6 Your comment is unintelligible. Please say what you mean clearly. Not "cracked it" and "doesn't like that". And which "IS NOT NULL"??